# What programming language is this Maximo automation script written in?

Tags: javascript, jython, rhino, maximo

I'm trying to teach myself Maximo automation scripting.

I've come across a [script in the Maximo help](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFGJ4_7.6.0/com.ibm.mbs.doc/autoscript/c_example_reuse.html). I want to try to understand how it works.

But first, what programming language is it written in?

```
service.log("I want to multiply 2 numbers and log the result")
from java.util import HashMap
a=3
b=2
ctx = HashMap()
ctx.put("x",a)
ctx.put("y",b)
service.invokeScript("MULTIPLY",ctx)
service.log("the result is "+str(ctx.get("z")))
```

**Edit:**

I've found a similar-looking script that is labelled as being **JS** ([download PDF](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/1004fd2b-1b51-411e-8df0-a8b02ca86272/media/Scritping76Features%20%285%29.pdf)):

```
importPackage(java.util)
importPackage(Packages.psdi.server)
var ctx = new HashMap();
ctx.put("url","http://localhost:7001/maximo/oslc/script/countryapi?_lid=wilson&_lpwd=wilson");
service.invokeScript("LIB_HTTPCLIENT",ctx);
var jsonResp = ctx.get("response");
var countries = JSON.parse(jsonResp);
```

However, it has semicolons at the end of each line, whereas the first script does not.

I don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: @JackBashford Ok. Sure. You're probably right. The reason I wasn't sure is: In Maximo scripting, I can use java libraries in many languages/scripts (for example, python). So, I see lots of references to `java.util` in python code (and other languages that aren't java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFGJ4_7.6.0/com.ibm.mbs.doc/autoscript/c_automation_scripts.html):

> The source code must be written in the languages that are supported by
>   the following script engines:
>
> - Mozilla Rhino, version 1.6 release 2
> - Jython, version 2.5.2

Your first snippet looks like Jython. The second looks like Javascript (Rhino).

Comment: `importPackage(java.util)` does not look like JavaScript...

Comment: @AlanH. I don't think it's standard JS. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java